# How to use flex-wrap with width transitions on css?

Tags: css, angular, animation, flexbox

I'm a junior developer and recently started to work with flex. What i'm trying to accomplish is to use flex-wrap in this snippet on code pen: https://codepen.io/knyttneve/pen/YgZbLO
Anyways, there is the css code:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    width: 100%;
    padding: 4% 2%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50vh;
}

.box {
    flex: 1;
    overflow: hidden;    
    margin: 0 2%;
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
    line-height: 0;
    transition: .5s;
}
```

With 3 or 4 boxes it's working nice, but I need (at the moment) to add up to 9, so the result, without flex-wrap, it's not what i'm looking for. So what I decided to do is to add flex-wrap, to leave the component itself readjust the elements to show according to the available with.

The problem is that, not only does it not work, but the hover effect no longer enlarges the images only horizontally, but also enlarges their height, which I don't want. I've attached images with the expected hover and the one I don't want, obtained by putting flex-wrap.

- [Hover effect I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RXZc.jpg)
- [Hover effect I don't want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qh2zh.jpg)

Could anyone tell me how I could achieve that effect, by keeping 4 or 5 images at most per row?